# Huawei Ads Kit onAdClosed() callback is not triggered

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am using Huawei Ads Kit in my project but when I am trying to close  InterstitialAd onAdClosed() callback is not triggered here is my code below

```
Activity activity = ... ;
String adUnitId = ... ;

InterstitialAd ad = InterstitialAd(activity);
ad.setAdUnitId(adUnitId);
ad.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
// ...
@Override public void onAdClosed()
{
    // Called when user presses the X button - OK.
    // Not called when user pressed the device back button - NOT OK.
}
};

ad.loadAd(...);
// (call when ready)
ad.show();
```

Is this behavior intentional?

Our app code relies on onAdClosed being called whenever the user closes the interstitial using both actions.

Code tested with:

Huawei P10 running EMUI 9.1.0.252 and HMS Core 4.0.0.334

Comment: Hi @Binary Princess I'm facing the same issue, did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate your issue, but in my case I'm getting the behavior you're expecting.

If you are using obfuscation, make sure to add this lines to your proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class com.huawei.openalliance.ad.** { *; }

-keep class com.huawei.hms.ads.** { *; }
```

and lastly
the documentation states that Ads Kit needs at least HMS Core 4.0.0 to work correctly.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/ads-sdk-guide